# GPIO register base address on Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: gpio, raspberry-pi4, base-address

According to the document "BCM2711 ARM Peripherals" Version 1, 5th February 2020, at page 83, "The GPIO base address is 0x7E21 5000."

(The link to the document is this: [BCM2711 ARM Peripherals](https://web.archive.org/web/20210629091209/https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/bcm2711/).)

From the command prompt, when I enter, "cat /proc/iomem", it displays, among other things, "gpio@7e200000".

My question is: Shouldn't these numbers be the same?

Comment: Nearest 2MB boundary below?  Is kernel using 2MB pages?

Comment: Thank you for your interest in my question.  I am not quite sure if the kernel is using 2MG pages.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, these numbers should indeed be the same.

Today I discovered that there is an error in the BCM2711 ARM Peripherals datasheet, also see this GitHub [issue](https://github.com/raspberrypi/documentation/issues/1569).

The correct GPIO base address is 0x7E20 0000.

Comment: FYI, that issue was updated to note that the datasheet has been fixed (as of rev 2, Sep 2020).